# How to add a custom action for a UIBarButtonItem in the StoryBoard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I want to have a couple of buttons in my iOS app at the bottom of the screen and so used a UIToolBar and added a couple of Bar Button Items to it. But I realized that these BarButtonItems are not considered to be regular buttons. So I am not able to set actions on mouse up on these. Is there a way to set a function to be called when these buttons are clicked? If this is not possible through the storyboard, can I access it programmatically?

Comment: So it turns out I was wrong. I can in fact assign individual action functions to the BarButtonItems. I needed to start from the view level where all IBActions will be visible and then drag and assign the functions to the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Select the `UIBarButtonItem`, Control+Dragging at the implementation section in .m file. Create an IBAction. You may put a `NSLog` statement to check the user tap.

Answer (score 0):

Create one outlet:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *menuBarBtn;
```

In ViewDidLoad or somewhere you can add like this:

```
[_menuBarBtn setAction: @selector( revealToggle:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not make an `IBAction` from the bar button item object or the code will not run.

In the document outline, control+drag from the button INSIDE the bar button item container. The `IBAction` should run normally now.